# c# DateTime Not Valid in the Given Context

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce

I posted a similar question but confusion set in so I feel the need to repost but with more clarity.

I am trying to insert into a database (SqlCompact3.5) colum which requires a DateTime datatype.

In order to get the current date & time i wish to use something like this:

```
SqlParameter vetCreated = new SqlParameter("@vetCreated", SqlDbType.DateTime);
vetCreated.Value = DateTime.Now;
```

However this results in a compile error saying **DateTime() is a 'method'. which is not valid in the given context.**

Any ideas?

[Link to Badly Asked Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090577/c-datetime-misunderstanding)

Comment: What is the exact error and on which line?

Comment: Duplicate of [c# DateTime Misunderstanding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090577/c-datetime-misunderstanding). Edit your original question, don't repost.

Comment: Be careful with your question asking.  there is an automated filter in place that bans users from asking questions if they do certain things (get lots of downvotes, repost questions, have questions deleted, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `DateTime.Now` to `System.DateTime.Now` and see if it compiles now.

Comment: Thanks this worked. It had been driving me nuts and everyone else i think. My apologies to Stackoverflow but thanks for coming through =)

Answer (score 1):

I have a hunch that you have `DateTime` method in your class. So when you call `DateTime.Now` compiler gets confused either you want to use `DateTime` class or method.

Prefix DateTime.Now with namespace `System.DateTime.Now`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a function named `DateTime()` in your class.

Change that.